# Edit existing PDF file using FPDF

Tags: pdf, fpdf

I have been search throughly on Google and stackoverflow, but it looks like I don't find any "clear" information regarding edit existing PDF file using FPDF ...

So, what I wan't to do is add a controlled copy marking on every PDF download from my site. To do this, the file source is already PDF file, and I want to edit them using FPDF ... But this "copy marking" is not on a new page, it is on the cover document. So there is no "add new page" process.

Any clue ?

Thank you for your help.

p.s. : Sorry for my bad english :p

Answer (score 7):

U Could Have Used [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) Library For this...

As I am using the same for exactly the same task...

see : [My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256153/how-to-get-the-exact-modified-pdf-using-fpdf-fpdi)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Guess it's time for trying out FPDI Library.